# Nuxt/Vue nuxt-link-active on scroll

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs

I'm using `<nuxt-link>` for my navigation and it adds a class `nuxt-link-active` to `<a>` tags, depending on which page I am.

For single-page (Portfolio) websites, the navigation usually just points to an anchor in the page (A div ID)

I'm using a mix of both and was wondering, if it's possible to add the link-active to a link when the user scrolls past a specific point.

Of course I can fire an event on scroll and then check, but then there's the problems with mounting and unmounting the functions and using `$refs` for each of the divs.

The main question is if Nuxt/Vue-router has this function built-in.

Comment: If you use `:to="{ path: "/", hash: '$section' }"` instead of `href="#anchor"` does it work out of the box?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy It works as simple navigation, but it doesn't add the class on scroll.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm trying to do something similar and I can't seem to find any answers to this. I could use intersect observer to add and remove classes, but this feels like a hacky thing to do.

Comment: @irunatbullets I just simply added a scroll listener that checks the current top offset and compares it to all the section offsets. If scroll's greater than section, emit an event that changes the active link.